# How to speedup inference FPS on mobile

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I am working on detection task on android using `TFLite`. However I am faced with problem conversion from `SavedModel`. I modified the conversion code as below and my model convert to .tflite sucsessfully but gives this error on mobile testing:

```
import tensorflow as tf
saved_model_dir = 'save/fine_tuning'
# tf.saved_model.save(model, saved_model_dir)


converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(saved_model_dir)
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [
  tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS, # enable TensorFlow Lite ops.
  tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS # enable TensorFlow ops.
]
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open("converted_model.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

inference error is [image: error]. I add

implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-select-tf-ops:0.0.0-nightly' to dependency and model works, but inference is very slow. Can anyone help for this problem?

Comment: You can try quantizing your TFLite model. See these [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/post_training_quantization).

Comment: My problem is that faster models runs slower.for example ICNET is faster than fast-scnn network. I don't find out.I am trying to solve that.

Comment: You can check the compatibility of various ops used by your model, with the `GpuDelegate`. See [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/gpu_advanced).

Comment: Remove "supported ops" flags and change your resize from nearest neighbor to bilinear. Try to use xnnpack with CPU delegate or NNAPI delegate. GPU delegate is more picky to operators.

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal can you clearly give some example?

Comment: @AlexK. thanks. I changed resize to bilinear and total ex. time decreased. but I initialized NNAPI delegate and it gives this error : Internal errir : Cant create interpereter : Didnt find op for builtn opcode 'RESIZE_BILINEAR' version 3.I am searching to solve it.

Comment: @Aminhabibi check this for NNAPI https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/neural-networks may come handy. Also look at https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/ops_version - tflite ops have different versions inside, looks like NNAPI does not like v3. Try GPU delegate and check out witch ops unsupported, maybe you can change them, or graph will partially run on GPU and rest on CPU.

Comment: Also if model's output correct try converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT] during conversion